# NoUISlider Bind with Input

Tags: javascript, html, nouislider

I am using noUISlider for allowing user to input number. It is working fine but now i want to add a input to be able to update the value of nouislider without dragging it. But some how i can not make it work. Below is how my code looks:

```
  <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="number" min="1" max="24" step="1" class="form-control input-sm" name="pointstopredicts" id="pointstopredicts" value="10" required="true" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div id="rangesliderPP"></div>
   </div>
```

And below is my JS Code:

```
<script>
   var skipSlider3 = document.getElementById('rangesliderPP');
   var pointstopredicts = document.getElementById('pointstopredicts');
   noUiSlider.create(skipSlider3, {
     start: [ 6 ],
     connect: 'lower',
      range: {
        'min': 1,
        'max': 24
      }
   });
   skipSlider3.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
        var value = values[handle];
      pointstopredicts.value = Math.round(value);
     });

     pointstopredicts.addEventListener('change', function(){
        skipSlider3.noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]);
      });
 </script>
```

When i change the value of input  I can see the change event trigger but also the update event of nouislider is being triggered which causes the input back to its old value. As per documentation of nouislider `set` event should not trigger `Update` event. Did i miss something.

JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/rehanazher/8bcx0uvp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove 'null'when setting value to slider.

should be like that:

```
   noUiSlider.create(skipSlider3, {
     start: [ 6 ],
     connect: [true,false],
     step: 1,
      range: {
        'min': 1,
        'max': 24
      }
   });
   skipSlider3.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
        var value = values[handle];

      pointstopredicts.value = Math.round(value);
     });

     pointstopredicts.addEventListener('change', function(){
        skipSlider3.noUiSlider.set([ this.value]);
      });
```

Comment: Sorry  , late just missed to tick the answer

Comment: How to set values when i've got multiple start points? (multi range)